# Why are we able to calculate volume on a 2D graph

Tags: calculus

When one is asked to rotate a plane across some line (with, say the shell method),  a 3D object is realized. However, since a standard graph involves only x and y, why are we able to calculate volume from a 2D graph.

Comment: You can always just add another axis to your $R^2$ i.e. $(x,y)$ plane to get a new $R^3$ i.e $(x,y,z)$ plane.

Comment: Then integrating on the 3D gives you 2D volume.

Comment: Is there an explanation for why this is the case that would be laymen enough for a non-math majors to understand?

Comment: The original line was never in 2D, it only looked that way because you have not rotated it yet. Best not to overthink some things?

Comment: The 3-d object is realized only if you choose it be solid. Otherwise, you are correct it does not become 3-d, it remains 2-D with different coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

We can not calculate a non-zero volume from a two-dimensional graph.

Take a two-dimensional graph, either one you found somewhere or one you created. What non-zero volume does it define? None!

You get a positive volume only when you take some other steps such as rotating the graph around a line. Even then you cannot say what the volume is unless you know **which** line the graph is rotated around.

When you do the shell method, what you’re actually measuring is the volume of each shell. In the limit as the shells' thickness goes to zero, all you need to know about each shell is its radius and length. You could measure those things anywhere on the shell, but it happens to be convenient to measure them where the shell intersects the original graph.

But in any case, the only way a two-dimensional object can have anything to do with a non-zero volume is if you have a known relationship between the two-dimensional object and a three-dimensional object whose volume you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is implicit in your question, and the key is in the *rotation.* When you rotate a plane region about some axis in that plane, all points of the region except those on the axis leave the plane -- in other words enter the third dimension. It is this that makes it possible. You can imagine this or draw a figure -- as the region sweeps out of its original plane, it always lies in one of a continuous "sequence" of planes, which generate some solid region in space.

In short, by rotating you *lift it out* of its initial plane.

Comment: Dear Down voter, could you please explain what's wrong with my answer. Thank you very much. Yours very sincerely.

Comment: The most annoying thing about this site is that it allows anyone to downvote without asking them to provide a reason. In fact, the downvote process is flawed in my opinion. A warning message should be given to the person providing the answer if there are mistakes and the answer should be marked as doubtful. If the person who provided the answer does not respond, the down-vote takes effect.

Comment: This is the best answer I've received. Don't know why there is a downvote, but take my upvote!